# Adding Annotation with PDF.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, annotations, mozilla, pdf.js

PDF.js is currently adding the ability to add annotation to a PDF, with an expected release on 1 May 23, with little to no documentation at all and no examples... I'm having a hard time putting things together, I was wondering if anyone could have a working example of a simple highlighter or a simple pen drawer?

I tried navigating through the `web` viewer in their codebase, but I'm having a hard time putting the pieces together.

Comment: The latest https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html already support `draw` annotation editor, the highlight is also experimental supported, you can set `enableHighlightEditor` option to `true` in the latest codebase to give it a try.

Comment: @Priestch thanks, looks like they're taking an optimized approach with the `viewer layer`.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation in PDF.Js is a client function for adding temporary data via mouse and keyboard in the browser screen. You can see the source file (my choice of a 1KB blank) is OUTSIDE the browser in the second image (from a local folder), but could be a remote fetched URL resource just like the image is. Once saved locally it will be converted into PDF additions (at the EndOfFile) by the worker.js functions.

[image]

[image]

Clearly the biggest addition is a binary image.
[image]

I can not show here the whole PDF, but see in the image below, is the "blank run time" instructions, in the top white part, where it terminates with `%%EOF`. Then the additions follow for 61 KB.

[image]

The important point to note is that, the first item is a reference to all 3 additions so the extra entries were not held in page as they need to be finally indexed as `/Annots [5 0 R 6 0 R 10 0 R]`.

- 5 = (Hello World!) with appearance as object 8
- 6 = /Rect [49.2 249.6 105 260.4] /InkList .... with additional metadata as object 7
- 10 is a stamping holder with more data in object 11 for the image as object 9

Now we get to the second EndOfFile and now there is a problem as it looks as if it breaks the normal rules since it is compacted, which should NOT be the case with this source.

```
12 0 obj
<< /Size 13 /Prev 213 /Type /XRef /Root 1 0 R /Info 3 0 R /Index [0 1 3 1 4 1 5 1 6 1 7 1 8 1 9 1 10 1 11 1 12 1] /ID [(¿¯]X9$'NˆcÀÉ£O) (#Eg‰«ÍïþÜº˜vT2)] /W [1 2 2] /Length 55>> stream
  ÿÿ¼  >  ž  ~  -  à  Y  ñü  ò£  óZ  
endstream
endobj
startxref
62298
%%EOF
```